# Eloquent - Cannot add foreign key constraint

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

Common question I guess, but I can't resolve it despite the informations I found online.

I've a sequence of hasMany relations :

- **User** *has many* **clients** has many **contracts** has many **materials**.

I did my best but I find myself confronted to this error :

> [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
>   SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint
>   (SQL: create table `clients` (`id` int unsigned not null, `user_id`
>   int unsigne     d null, ...) default character set utf8mb4 collate
>   utf8mb4_unicode_ci engine = InnoDB)
>
> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key
>   constraint

Migrations :

```
class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->engine = 'InnoDB';

            // Keys

            $table->increments('id');

            // Other

            ...
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::disableForeignKeyConstraints();
        Schema::dropIfExists('clients');
        Schema::drop('users');
        Schema::enableForeignKeyConstraints();
    }
}

class CreateClientsTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('clients', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->engine = 'InnoDB';

            // keys

            $table->unsignedInteger('id')->unique();
            $table->primary('id');

            $table->unsignedInteger('user_id')
                  ->nullable();
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')
                  ->onDelete('cascade');

            // others
            ...
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::disableForeignKeyConstraints();
        Schema::dropIfExists('contracts');
        Schema::drop('clients');
        Schema::enableForeignKeyConstraints();
    }
}

class CreateContractsTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('contracts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->engine = 'InnoDB';

            // Keys

            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('contract_number')->unique();

            $table->unsignedInteger('client_id');
            $table->foreign('client_id')->references('id')->on('clients')
                  ->onDelete('cascade');


            // Others

            ...
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::disableForeignKeyConstraints();
        Schema::dropIfExists('materials');
        Schema::drop('contracts');
        Schema::enableForeignKeyConstraints();
    }
}

class CreateMaterialsTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('materials', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->engine = 'InnoDB';

            // Keys

            $table->increments('id');

            $table->string('contract_number')->unique();

            $table->unsignedInteger('contract_id');
            $table->foreign('contract_id')->references('id')->on('contracts')
                  ->onDelete('cascade');

            // Others

            ...
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('materials');
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Are you using mysql/mariadb? And if yes, what version?

Comment: Are your columns same data type?

Comment: I'm using mysql, and yes they're...

Answer (score 1):

You should add `->unsigned()` to all your key columns you have.
Please use this instead of `unsignedInteger()` and set the type to `integer()`

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that your migrations are running in the correct order? They should be running in the order you provided in your example code. I can't seem to recreate the error on my end using your exact example migrations.

The order is determined by the date at the beginning of the migration's filename. Alternatively, you could create all these tables in the same migration to force the order that way.